# How to Access Objects in a Class

Tags: swift, class

I am trying to make a function create a new player (`registerNewPlayer`) from a registration form. The problem I am running into is that once the player object is created, I cannot access the player information to change variables such as the player name or the gold value of the player. How do I access objects in a class without an identifier or how can I create a function create a new player with an identifier?

```
class Players {

    var name: String
    var gold: Int
    var accountPassword: String

    init (name:String, gold: Int, accountPassword: String) {
        self.name = name; self.gold = gold; self.accountPassword = accountPassword
    }
}

func registerNewPlayer (playerName: String, password: String) -> Players {
    let registree = Players(name: playerName, gold: 0, accountPassword: password)
    return registree
}

registerNewPlayer(playerName: "Bob", password: "abc")
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you're asking. Could you please rephrase what you're trying to do in greater detail?

Comment: Yes. When the player "Bob" is created. I have no way of changing the player class variables for "Bob" such as the player name, password, and gold. How can I change these variables when creating a player object via a function

Answer (score 2):

The fix was to place the returned object into an array of players in the init {} statement of the Players class. This allows the players to be identified by the index number of the array.

Comment: You’re right that by using them in an array you do not have to name the variables as such and can access them using the index. Perhaps it’s not very flexible to append to the array in the `Players.init()` method because sometimes you might want to make a player object without putting it in the array. Instead you could use `array.append(Players(name: "Bob", password: "password"))` to add the new instance to the array in a cleaner way.

Comment: @Chris Thank you, I will keep that in mind. If there is another way to create a variable by way of the player setting the identifier via a function, please let me know. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: It’s a pleasure. All the best for developing the game!

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the new player to a variable so you can access it later.

```
var playerOne = registerNewPlayer(playerName: "Bob", password: "abc")

print(playerOne.name) // Prints "Bob"
```

Comment: Yes, but the above code creates a new player object by typing in the code yourself. Players playing the game won't be expected to type these things. I want their information from a registration form to go into the player class as their own object

Comment: Do you have code for your registration form? You could just call `registerNewPlayer()` with the data that the user entered in the form.

Comment: If I were to do that, then I wouldn't be able to change variables of the player class for the created object, such as gold. Creating a new player  by registerNewPlayer() doesn't provide an identifier

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. This code is how you would create a new player, and afterward you could change the name and so on. People playing the game wouldn't type this because presumably your app would have some kind of user interface that would let them enter the details.

Comment: I am trying to do just as you said. I want the a player to sign up on a registration form and to pass the information from the sign up form to a player object. I hard wrote in 
     registerNewPlayer(playerName: "Bob", password: "abc")
to make it more simple. Whether you create the player by this function with passed in information from a registration form or if you hard write it in, there is still not an identifier attached to the created object to allow me to change the gold variable later on in the game.

Comment: Use `gold: Int = 0` in your `init()` declaration. Then you can set the gold any time with `playerOne.gold = 42` for example.

Comment: the identifier "playerOne" is never assigned. Where are you getting playerOne from? The code I provided does indeed create a Players object with name of 'Bob', gold of 0, and password of 'abc'. How can I edit those variables now?

Comment: @JaredPieniazek By doing exactly what he said? They're declared as `var`, so you can just the dot syntax to change their values...

Comment: My answer uses the playerOne example. In your code you did not assign the new player to a variable, which is why you cannot access it. The name “Bob” is only a property of that particular `Players` object. You cannot access it using the name Bob. You could use: `var Bob = registerNewPlayer(playerName: "Bob", password: "whatever")` Then you can set Bob’s gold using `Bob.gold = 42`

Comment: I see... but your example still requires hard coding of "var Bob =" to create the identifier. My example has "registree" in the same place that you would have Bob in your example. My function creates an object without an identifier. I think it would be easier to help create a function that adds an identifier at this point

Comment: Also, you don’t really need the `registerNewPlayer()` function. You can just make a new player directly: `var Bob = Players(name: "Bob", gold: 0, password: "abc")`

Comment: I don't want to directly create the player. The gamer is going to register and their data is going to be passed into the code to create a new player. The registerNewPlayer() function is needed to create a new player object

Comment: @CharlesSrstka, that does not work. The dot syntax does not work because there is no identifier

Comment: But it’s not needed. Code is all about abstraction. You need to be able to refer to the player object some way, but the gamer does not need to know how you do this. They will never see your variable name. Presumably if they see their username they will just see their player object’s name property, such as “Bob”. Your `registree` only has scope inside the `registerNewPlayer()` function. It means nothing outside it. That’s where our code is different: setting the player object to a variable is not the same as your function returning a player object.

Comment: @Chris I understand what you are saying. I guess I am confused on how you can create an identifier for your player then. I don't mind having var Bob = Players(name: "Bob", gold: 0, password: "abc") but how is that variable of Players (Bob) going to be created when a new user signs up? Here's the scenario... say you're Bob... You sign up. I am not available to edit the code and type in the var Bob = Players(name: "Bob", gold: 0, password: "abc"). How will I be able to increase your gold in the game? I won't be able to edit the gold variable for your player object.

Comment: Ok, your form might have two textfields for the user to enter their name and password. You might need to look up a tutorial on using UIKit. When the user taps a button, you would call this code, as an example: `var player = Players(name: nameTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text)` Then you can always get the player’s player object with `player` and when they collect gold, use (for example): `player.gold += 1`

Comment: How is your example different from my code with the exception of using var player instead of let registree? I have fixed the issue by appending the created object into an array. It can be called by the index number of the array. I'm sorry but your example does not do what I am trying to do. What happens when you have 2 players? They can't be both under the variable 'player'. Am I wrong in what I am saying?

Comment: Once your function returns registree, it stops existing because registree was only the name for that player object inside the function. You haven’t stored it anywhere to access it outside the function. Setting it to a variable achieves this and is easier than using an array index. With two players just use a different variable name or just store them all in an array anyway: `var allPlayers = [Players]()` This makes an empty array tray to receive objects of class Players. You could increase the first players gold with `allPlayers[0].gold += 1`

Comment: I apologize but you are mistaken and the only way to do this is by using an array, as I pointed out in the previous post I made and as you stated in your previous post

Comment: I’m out of ideas. I hope you get it working @JaredPieniazek :)